# Excluding NULL column datasets in Doctrine query

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine, expression

I am working on a Doctrine/Symfony project and I am attempting to retrieve results only if a reference is set. The column for the relation can be populated with reference IDs or it can be null if no reference is "set". Currently, I am unable to exclude the datasets with a null column.

```
$qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();

$qb->select('am', 'lb')->from('MyBundle:Brand', 'am')
->leftJoin('MyBundle:XBuyer', 'lb')
->where('lb.id = am.buyer')
->andWhere('am.buyer IS NOT NULL');
```

Another format I tried:

```
$qb->select('am', 'lb')->from('MyBundle:Brand', 'am')
->leftJoin('MyBundle:XBuyer', 'lb')
->where('lb.id = am.buyer')
->andWhere('am.buyer != :buyer_id_val')
->setParameter('buyer_id_val', '');
```

also

```
$qb->select('am', 'lb')->from('MyBundle:Brand', 'am')
->leftJoin('MyBundle:XBuyer', 'lb')
->where('lb.id = am.buyer')
->andWhere($qb->expr()->isNotNull('am.buyer'));
```

Buyer is the reference to another table - it is `buyer_id` in the brand's table, followed by:

```
$data = $qb->getQuery()->execute(null, Query::HYDRATE_SCALAR);
```

No idea what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: `->where('lb.id = am.buyer')` -- Don't you have a relation between those two entities? Perhaps `@ManyToOne`?

Comment: Where you write this query in  repository class or in controller ?

Comment: ->andWhere('am.buyer IS NOT NULL')  try this

Comment: thanks for the support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem was that i'm still thinking in the context of the database (other projects) but in the case of using doctrine it was necessary to think in the context of an object - more specific if there is an relation between entities.

the actual IS NOT NULL expression wasnt the problem - the problem was the actual leftJoin on an entitiy instead of the relation-"name".

```
$qb->select('am', 'lb')->from('MyBundle:Brand', 'am')
->leftJoin('am.buyer', 'lb')
->where('am.buyer IS NOT NULL')
->andWhere('lb.id = am.buyer');
```

thanks guys for all the comments and support in this little timeframe

Answer (score 0):

in my case,

```
$qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
```

generated :

```
Too few arguments to function Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository::createQueryBuilder()…
```

I finally wrote:

```
$qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder('am');
$qb->select('am')
    ->leftJoin('am.buyer', 'lb')
    ->where('lb.id = am.buyer')
    ->andWhere('am.buyer IS NOT NULL');
    ->orderBy('am.id', 'ASC')
    ->setMaxResults(30)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult()
;
```

which works fine!
Nota: with Symfony 4.2.3